# CSS to align page title center width

Tags: html, css

Can anyone see what I'm missing. I'm just trying to align the page title center width. However, nothing works. The h1 element doesnt to go to 100% width of its parent container (really the browser width), no matter what I try (I've tried 20 different combinations of values)...

```
.ast-archive-description {
    background: #000000 !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.ast-archive-title {
    text-align:center !important;
    color: #FFCC00 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

It's on this page:
https://holyspiritprints.com/category/fine-art-prints/sweet-psalms-arizona/

Comment: Please create a [mcve] within the question instead of linking out to an external site.

Comment: That's not possible. It's only visible when fully inside the wordpress theme and all it's CSS/settings...centering a standalone div takes 2 seconds, but this is not that and for some reason (the question), it's not responding to the CSS settings shown above, which "should" work.

Comment: It is always possible. Doing the work to isolate the problem into a reproducible example will often lead to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scraping about a bit in your page, I have noticed a lot of rule overriding (where the rule is crossed out). This should be avoided as it makes it hard to see what rules apply where as well as adding unneccary css. The offending rule here is this:

```css
body.archive .ast-archive-description {
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Disabling it centeres the text.
If editing this css isn't an option you can override it to unset

```css
body.archive .ast-archive-description {
    max-width: unset !important;
}
```

Also note that you have included the same CSS file twice (I don't know if this is wordpress' fault)

Comment: ah...worked perfectly...I really couldn't find that part, and yes, by the time wordpress and themes and plugins get loaded, things can be quite a mess :( Nature of the beast. Many thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try to add the following:

```
.ast-archive-description {
  max-width: none;
}
```